# Accepting jobs and just collecting money while waiting to get terminated?

Tags: united-states, contracts

I was thinking, could you just take advantage of the hot software job market and sign up for a bunch of remote positions and do enough to be present but otherwise be awful so you can collect a month of pay before being fired and maybe even go for government positions to collect three months of pay before being fired.

Would this work?

Comment: Define "work"? Do you mean "is this legal?" And if so, you'll need to add where you are. Your local government probably has an opinion on this.

Comment: @Erik I live in Texas

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are people doing exactly this. The issue is of course, that you won't have any chance of a decent career once the job market turns around. And it always does, sooner or later.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking us for advice on how to defraud people.

Comment: This question appears to be trolling. At a minimum, it's so obviously ridiculous that it doesn't even bear dignifying with a response.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we don't give advice on how to commit fraud

Comment: Note that I have seen people changing company several times a year for 20 or more years and still being hired. For me this is a huge red flag, and I would expect the same from any HR, but some people seem to get away with it. Most of the time these persons confirmed the red flag and indeed were let go quite fast...

Comment: It's also not clear to me whether OP is focusing on "multiple full time positions" aspect (which indeed is fraudulent), or just slacking into 1 position at a time until getting fired, rince and repeat. Which doesn't look like a clever career plan but isn't fraud and actually could work (cfr my previous comment)

Answer (score 13):

Will it work? Probably for one position or two.

You might get 2-5 free months of salary out of it. You would also ruin your professional reputation, even if not detected as fraud. Your own plan is to look so unqualified that you get fired from multiple jobs in a row (or in parallel actually).

So yeah, if you need money quickly and don't plan on having a good job thereafter (lets say you need to pay back that drug money to the mob or they will kill you, or maybe you want to buy a nice car before you die of that fatal illness that was diagnosed last week, you know... Netflix material) that would probably work.

If you plan on living longer than a few months, a normal happy life, it's probably not a very smart idea.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a lawyer, but a few things to consider:

- Contract of employment is a legally binding
- Intent to defraud

While I think it would be possible, so is committing any other crime. I don't think it would be hard to discover, and you could find yourself in trouble.

While not a lawyer I can't see how this doesn't count as fraud and breach of contract.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the legal aspects of this. If the OP's proposed behavior is not illegal, it should be.

Answer (score 1):

While not at the contracting company I was at, we did have a situation like that unfold but in a morbid way.

This guy got hired on this contract but he was more interested in the life insurance policy than anything else. It was very odd and strange but they said if he passed away while employed, his spouse would get a full year's pay regardless of when he passes away. So he came on board, one month later went to the hospital and died a short time later. Apparently he found out he had terminal cancer and was given a few months to live but he had no life insurance but had his military retirement but once he passes away his wife would not get it since he never took out an survival benefits or life insurance when he retired.

While there is a certain stigma that government work is easy, it is not. Most of them require a lengthy background check. Let me say getting fired from a government job would be very harmful to your life. There will be a red flag in your record that would immediately prevent you from ever getting a contract or government job. When you apply to a contract position, they run a soft review on you before even filling out the government forms and if there is a red flag on your record, they would immediately not consider you for hire regardless if said red flag can be explained. Also, there will be a permanent mark on your record that could prevent you from passing normal background checks to get hired. Not only that when you do get a government job, they run a background check one of which checks your prior work history. They would see you were fired multiple times in short order and that is an area of concern. Failing a background check for a government job is just as bad as getting fired from a government job. That means your record is so bad and unforgivable that they aren't willing to trust you even being around a secure area. Overall it is very stupid to get fired from a government job.

Overall though, I do not recommend this approach and instead work at places to work. I guess in theory you could hire into multiple remote positions, set up a direct pay, and avoid work as long as possible until you get paid. Probably wouldn't be a full week's pay either as they no doubt would fire you on your first or second day of no contact.

Comment: Usually life insurances wouldn't apply if you didn't disclose such a disease before getting enrolled, while knowing your condition.

Comment: @LaurentS. True, but I don't think that applies to the one at your workplace. It's automatic, no enrollment or disclosure needed.

Answer (score 0):

Of course. Entering a contract in bad will can work like any other scam or illegal behavior. Do you have three months of pay guaranteed from day one? Sounds weird (especially to deter frauds like you)

Comment: I am basically betting on them letting probation die or HR being lazy or whatever.